# Solving the Liouville-Von Neumann Equation for stationary solutions: Does it make sense to have solutions that don't qualify as density-operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, density-operator

I'm currently calculating the dynamics of the density operator for a 3-level system. To do this, I've set up a Hamiltonian as:

\begin{align}
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \hbar  \delta _q & \hbar  \tilde{\Omega }_q & 0 \\
 \hbar  \Omega _q & 0 & \hbar  \Omega _d \\
 0 & \hbar  \tilde{\Omega }_d & \hbar  \delta _d \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
For each of the spontaneous decay channels, the lindblad form of the decay is:
\begin{align}
D_\sigma[\rho]=  (\sigma \rho \sigma^{\dagger} - \frac{1}{2}(\sigma^\dagger \sigma \rho  +  \rho \sigma^\dagger \sigma)
\end{align}

Then overall, the time evolution can be cast into the following form:

\begin{align}
\dot{\rho}= \frac{i}{\hbar}[\rho, H] + \Gamma_{12} D_{\sigma_{12}}[\rho] + \Gamma_{13} D_{\sigma_{13}}[\rho] + \Gamma_{23} D_{\sigma_{23}}[\rho] = \mathcal{L}[\rho]
\end{align}
With $\mathcal{L}$ being a linear map acting on the operator $\rho$.

I now try to find the steady state solution of the system, by simply finding the operator $\rho$ that $\mathcal{L}$ computes to 0 - If you want, the kernel of the system.
I do so by using a computer algebra system, and perform the calculation symbolically.
Now, when I find the 0-space, what usually happens is that the solutions I get have complex diagonal elements, which means that my solution is not hermitian.

Of course, solutions of eigenvalue equations are just solutions up to a complex constant, but by that alone I am not able to cure the non-hermicity in this case.

Which makes me wonder: Should I even expect to get a solution that qualifies as a density matrix? (Self-Adjoint, and trace 1), by finding the kernel of the Liouvillian? I know that the Liouvillian is trace and hermiticity preserving, but does that also play a role in my calculation here, where I didn't pick a density-operator $\rho(0)$ for a start?

Comment: The identity is always in the kernel which, up to renormalization, qualifies as a valid density matrix.

Comment: @LPZ this however doesn't tell me wether every linear independent element of the Kernel does, up to renormalization, qualify as a valdi density matrix.

Comment: As you’ve said yourself, there are elements of the kernel that are non valid density matrices even after renormalisation. If I understand correctly, your original question is whether there are density matrices in the kernel. The answer is yes just by this simple example.

Comment: @LPZ The identity matrix is not always in the kernel. It is always a left eigenvector, that is, an eigenvector of $\mathcal L^\dagger$, but only a right eigenvector if the channel is unital.

Comment: @Noiralef aren't eigenvectors of $\mathcal{L}$ what I'm interested in, in that case? If I shove all this super-operator terminology asside, it's just a linear map that can have a kernel - no? So why should I be interested in $\mathcal{L}^{\dagger}$?

Comment: I was responding to LPZ. For your question, I don't think that $\mathcal L^\dagger$ will help you much. Generally, the fact that $\mathcal L^\dagger 1 = 0$ is useful since $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal L^\dagger$ have the same spectrum. It thus proves that the kernel of a Lindbladian is never empty.

Comment: @Noiralef I just discovered that I had a mistake in my initial formula - thus I know see that $1$ isn't an eigenvector of $\mathcal{L}$ - To understand your comment on this, what actually is the adjoint of a super-operator?

Comment: An adjoint is always defined with respect to an inner product. On the space of operators, we usually talk about the inner product $\langle \sigma, \rho \rangle = tr(\sigma^\dagger \rho)$. The adjoint is the (super)operator satisfying $\langle \mathcal L^\dagger \sigma, \rho \rangle = \langle \sigma, \mathcal L \rho \rangle$. The matrix representation of $\mathcal L^\dagger$ (with entries $\langle \rho_i, \mathcal L^\dagger \rho_j\rangle$) is the adjoint transpose of the matrix representation of $\mathcal L$.

Comment: You can check for example the section about adjoint master equations in Breuer & Petruccione. The adjoint generator introduced there is precisely the adjoint of the Lindbladian in the sense I just defined. As far as I remember, Breuer doesn't talk about inner products and adjoints in general, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pondered a bit, and I think I have the answer to the question:

If $\rho$ is part of the Kernel, that is

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}[\rho]= 0 
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
 \mathcal{L}[\rho]^{\dagger}=0  \\
=(\frac{i}{\hbar}[\rho, H])^{\dagger} - \sum_i \Gamma_i ( \sigma_i \rho \sigma_i^{\dagger} - \frac{1}{2} ( \rho \sigma_i^{\dagger} \sigma + \sigma_i^{\dagger} \sigma \rho))^{\dagger} \\
=(\frac{i}{\hbar}[\rho^{\dagger}, H]) - \sum_i \Gamma_i ( \sigma_i \rho^{\dagger} \sigma_i^{\dagger} - \frac{1}{2} (\sigma_i^{\dagger} \sigma \rho^{\dagger} + \rho^{\dagger} \sigma_i^{\dagger} \sigma)) \\
\end{align}
because $H$ is hermitean.
Then
\begin{align}
= \mathcal{L}[\rho^{\dagger}]= 0
\end{align}
That means, when $\rho$ is in the kernel, then $\rho^{\dagger}$ is as well, so for every element $\rho$ of the kernel, $\rho + \rho^{\dagger}$ is as well in the kernel, and qualifies (up to normalization of the trace} as a density operator.

Comment: Actually, you’d need to also check positivity of $\rho$ for it to be a density matrix (or else you could have negative probabilities). This is where knowing that the identity is in the kernel comes in handy. By convex combination, you can construct a valid density matrix.